# Eigen solver for sparse matrix product

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I want to use Eigen to compute L_1^{-1}L_2, where both L_1 and L_2 are lower triangular matrices and are stored as column oriented sparse matrices in Eigen. 
I tried the Eigen triangular solver. However, that requires L_2 to be dense.

Comment: The inverse of a sparse matrix is usually dense, therefore `L_1^{-1}*L_2` will be dense as well. Are you sure, you need to store the matrix, instead of just computing products/solving systems on the fly?

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your response. I actually have guarantee that L_1^{-1} is also sparse.

Answer (score 1):

The `solve` method in fact is not overloaded for sparse rhs, however you can use the `solveInPlace` method like so (I did not actually try this):

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> foo(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> const& L1, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> const& L2)
{
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> res = L2;
    L1.triangularView<Eigen::Lower>().solveInPlace(res);
    return res;
}
```

Still you should consider if you actually need the full matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed I need to compute the inverse of a spd matrix K = LL^T, where L is very sparse. My solution is to call triangular solve twice: L_inv = L.triangularView<Lower>().solve(Identity) and L.transpose().triangularView<Upper>.solve(L_inv). Is this the right way to do it in Eigen?

Comment: Instead of the second solve, you can compute `L_inv.transpose()*L_inv`

Comment: But if L is sparse, isn't **L.transpose().triangularView<Upper>.solve(L_inv)** faster than **L_inv.transpose()*L_inv**?

Comment: I can't think of good examples where a sparse solve would be faster than a sparse product. To find out if this happens in your case you need to benchmark!

Comment: Thanks for your help!